# Excel Macro: iterate through workbooks and print individual sheets from each

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

The steps I need to carry out are repetitive, but I'm not sure how to iterate through each workbook and then each sheet.

My task is to:

1. Look in a folder: (Source folder)
2. Iterate through each workbook in that folder (Source file)
3. Print each of the 4 worksheets (sheet name) in each workbook to a PostScript Printer (Printer Name/Path).
4. Name the printed to file PS file = Source file+sheet name
5. Final PS output files placed in final folder (destination folder)
6. Original workbook closed and not saved.

I searched for iteration VBA/Macro and have seen some ideas, but I'm unsure how the code looks when it's working through workbooks and worksheets.

Also, the PS printer is done through Printing To File. Does this cause problems.

**UPDATED WITH CODE I'VE TRIED SO FAR:**

```
Sub Make_PS_Files()

Dim path2 As String, path3 As String

path2 = "Drive:\Source folder\"
path3 = " Drive:\Destination folder\"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=path2 + "File_Name.XLS"
Sheets("Specific_Sheet_Name1").Activate

  Application.ActivePrinter = "\\PRINTER NAME\LOCATION:"

  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Collate _
   :=True, Prtofilename:=True
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, Prtofilename:=path3 + " Specific_Sheet_Name1.ps"


Sheets("Specific_Sheet_Name2").Activate

  Application.ActivePrinter = "\\VS PRINTER NAME\LOCATION:"

  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Collate _
   :=True, Prtofilename:=True
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, Prtofilename:=path3 + " Specific_Sheet_Name2.ps"


Sheets("Specific_Sheet_Name3").Activate

  Application.ActivePrinter = "\\ PRINTER NAME\LOCATION:"

  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Collate _
   :=True, Prtofilename:=True
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, Prtofilename:=path3 + " Specific_Sheet_Name3.ps"
ActiveWorkbook.Close


Sheets("Specific_Sheet_Name4").Activate

  Application.ActivePrinter = "\\ PRINTER NAME\LOCATION:"

  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Collate _
   :=True, Prtofilename:=True
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut copies:=1, Prtofilename:=path3 + " Specific_Sheet_Name4.ps"
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Apologies for not posting this last night when I posted. It seems very long winded for what it is doing. I thought it could be polished a bit more so it is more universal and can be pointed at any workbook and any number of sheets.

Not all the sheets have the Specific_Sheet_Name, so I would like to iterate through without reference to the name.

Comment: @Jmax: Apologies for not posting the code. I've added what I have above.

Comment: @Mike, are you actually using a different printer for each sheet? If not, then you only need to set the `Application.ActivePrinter` once. Also, you should save the value of `ActivePrinter` before changing it and then reset it when you are done (or if an error occurs).

Comment: @Harry. Save the value of active printer? I found the value of the active printer by recording a macro, and then pasting in the apropriate values. How do you save it/reset it? And why?

Comment: @Mike You can save it by storing it's value in a variable. If you select a printer other than the user's default printer, they'll be surprised if they try to print manually in that instance of Excel. Instead of using their system default, it will use the one you selected.

Comment: @Harry. Thanks. I'll look into this and give it a go.

Comment: @Mike: no problem. I see that you've found a good answer and some direction, that's the important thing after all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the workbooks in a folder using the [FileSystemObject](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject.html) by using the [Folder](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/folder.html) and [File](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/file.html) objects. (Remember to add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`)

Iterating through worksheets is as easy as a `For Each` over the `Workbook.Sheets` collection.

Finally, you can print the worksheet using the [PrintOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.printout%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method on each worksheet to print them. Just make sure to set the `PrintToFile` parameter to true.

If you need more direction than that, I suggest following @JMax's advice and post some of what you've tried already.

**UPDATE**

To iterate through workbooks using `FileSystemObject`:

```
Sub Make_PS_Files()
  Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim source As Scripting.Folder
  Dim wbFile As Scripting.File
  Dim book As Excel.Workbook

  Set source = fso.GetFolder("Drive:\Source folder\")
  For Each wbFile In source.Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xls" Then
      Set book = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
      ' Print out the workbook
    End If
  Next 
End Sub
```

And to iterate through the worksheets in a workbook:

```
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

For Each sheet in book.Sheets
  sheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="\\Printer:", PrintToFile:=True, _
                 PrToFileName:=fso.BuildPath(destination, sheet.Name & ".ps")
Next
```

Keep in mind that this has no error handling, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Not sure how the file and folder objects are included in the code above. As you can see, my code is quite basic.

Comment: Thanks. This has given me the framework to properly attack this little project. Much appreciated.